# Infinite Tableview in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using **Splitview Controller** in my **iPhone** app with **Potrait mode** only.

**My try in MasterView.swift**

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let maximumOffset = (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)

        if (currentOffset >= maximumOffset) { 
            print("call API")
        }
    }
```

**Problem**

I am getting wrong Tableview y content offset as **-64**.
even though it has Navigation BAR

```
    <UITableView: 0x7f8beb046400; frame = (0 0; 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; 
autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7f8bea56dd20>; 
layer = <CALayer: 0x7f8bea565730>; 
contentOffset: {0, -64}; 
contentSize: {600, 0}>
```

**Thank you**

**Help me to solve this**

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is here. Are you asking about infinitely scrolling table views? Are you asking about the incorrect content offset? Are you asking about using table views in split view controllers? (Also, if you're writing for iPhone only and portrait only then UISplitViewController is redundant. Just use UINavigationController).

Comment: Also, did you look at the property `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`?

Comment: Do you want to recognise when table view reaches at bottom?

Comment: @Fa.Shapouri that's what I was thinking originally.

Answer (score 2):

> I am getting wrong Tableview y content offset as -64. even tough it has Navigation BAR

The `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property is `YES` by default, so that content in scroll views (remember that `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`) is offset so that the top of the content appears below the nav bar and status bar, but can scroll up underneath those bars. The normal height of the nav bar and status bar together is 64.

If you're not getting the appearance you want, you may need to set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `NO`, but I've usually found that that's the wrong answer. It looks like you're just using the offset to determine when to call some method in some other framework, so the best answer might be to just take the offset into account when calculating whether or not to make the call.

Answer (score 0):

I used below code in swift to determine when my table view arrive at bottom, I hope you find it useful;

```
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
         if tableView.contentSize.height >= tableView.frame.size.height {
            if(tableView.contentOffset.y >= 
               (tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.frame.size.height)) {
                //user has scrolled to the bottom   
               }
               else {
               //table view is not in bottom
               }
          }
     }
```

Answer (score -2):

This happens because your navigation bar is translucent.

**Option 1: You don't need a translucent navigation bar.**

Set your `UINavigationBar` `translucent` property to `false` or unmark the `Translucent` checkbox in your `UINavigationBar` in your storyboard to remove this.

[image]

**Option 2: You want a translucent navigation bar.**

You need to take the status bar and navigation bar heights into account. The total offset will be the status bar height plus the navigation bar height:

```
let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height
let navBarHeight = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height
let offset = statusBarHeight + navBarHeight
```

Comment: What if the OP wants a translucent nav bar? This may avoid the problem, but I don't think it's really a solution.

Comment: @paulvs what you are doing here (in both cases) is unnecessarily complicated and achieves the same result as Caleb's answer. However, due to the ambiguity of the actual question, we don't actually know what the problem is yet.

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends what the question is. Which is still ambiguous. The op mentions infinite table view in the title.